# Using regexp_replace how do t replace a string with an exception

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

How do I replace all occurrences of `' sub.*'` with the exception of `' substation.*'`?

```
regexp_replace("CleanString",' sub.*',' ', 'ig')
```

I have tried using various combinations of groupings () but still not getting it.

Using postgres `regexp_replace()`

Comment: Could you fix the syntax? The question is incomprehensible as it is.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It seemed clear enough to me, but I've tidied it up anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression normally matches only things that are there, not things that are not there - you cannot simply put an "if-then-else" in there.

However, Postgres's regex support, [the manual page for which is here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) includes "lookahead" and "lookbehind" expressions.

In your case, you want a *negative lookahead":

> `(?!re)`  negative lookahead matches at any point where no substring matching re begins (AREs only)

It's important to note the phrase "at any point" - lookarounds are "zero width", so `(?!station)` doesn't mean "something other than `station`", it means "a position in the string where `station` isn't coming next".

You can therefore construct your query like this:

```
' sub(?!station).*'
```

That will match any of "sub", "foo sub", " subbar", or "foo subbar", but not any of "substation", "foo substation", " substationbar", or "foo substationbar". Since the `(?!station)` is zero-width, and the next token is `.*`, it's fine for nothing to come after " sub".

If you want there to be *something* after the "sub", you could instead write:

```
' sub(?!station).+'
```

The `.+` means "at least one of something", so it will still match " subbar" and "foo subbar", but will no longer match " sub" or "foo sub".

Comment: Excellent explanation and suggestions. Works perfectly! Thanks IMSoP